# python csv writing in row column format

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, csv

I have csv file in the order

a

1  2  3

4  5  6
7  8  9
b

7  8  9

4  5  6
1  2  3

how can I change it to the following form 
a 1 2 3
   4 5 6
   7 8 9
b 7 8 9
   4 5 6
   1 2 3

with a, b being the first column and the number in the second, third and fourth column respectively

my code is:

```
with open('csv_test.csv', 'w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow([a, b, c])
    wr.writerow([1, 2, 3])
    wr.writerow([4, 5, 6])
    wr.writerow([7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

I note that you are using the csv module.

This code reads each line. If the line consists of a single field, the contents of the field are considered a header, and are remembered for the next line

The after the next line is read, the header and the contents of the line are written out, then the header is replaced with an empty string, so subsequent lines get a blank field in the first column, and numbers in the second, third etc columns.

```
import csv
with open("infile.csv","r") as infile:
    with open("myfile.csv","w") as myfile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile) 
        wr = csv.writer(myfile)

        column1 = ""
        for fields in reader:
            if len(fields) == 1:
                column1 = fields[0]
            else:
                wr.writerow([column1]+fields)
                column1 = ""
```